# AutoHotkey SetWorkingDir passed parameter not working

Tags: autohotkey

For some reason when I pass a parameter from one script to another, it does not want to use it.

I have the following code in one script:

```
Run, %A_AhkPath% "RunAll.ahk" %PathChoice%
```

The variable %PathChoice% has the Directory that should be used in the second script like so:

```
Run test.exe %PathChoice%
```

It is having trouble finding the Directory that the variable is storing, and the directory exist. If I use the actual name of the directory is works just fine. So what am i doing wrong here

Comment: Where is `test.exe` located?

Comment: C:\NewTest\V1\ - This is what is in the %PathChoice% Variable and this directory does exist

Comment: Can you try if this line of code will work?  ``Run test.exe C:\NewTest\V1\``  Something tells me it has nothing to do with the variable not being passed.

Comment: Or in the second script, do a ``msgbox, %PathChoice%`` check and see if the variable is actually there.

Comment: Run test.exe C:\NewTest\V1\ works. now in the second script wouldn't the Passed Variable be in %1%, instead of the variable name?

Comment: Anybody have any ideas on why this is not working?

Comment: I would usually use full paths, and put double quotes around filenames:
e.g. `Run, "%A_AhkPath%" "%vDir1%\RunAll.ahk" "%PathChoice%"` and
`Run, "%vDir2%\test.exe" "%PathChoice%"`